# Trim leading zeros in a react calculator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I'm learning react and for that purpose I'm implementing a react calculator, and I would like to remove the leading zeros, in order to show the number without these zeros, for example if I get a 07, in the display I have to show just the 7, but I have for example: 7+15+08, it's the same I have to show immediately 7+15+8. I'm using react components:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    let output = this.state.output;
    let value = e.target.textContent;
    //Im doing some validations for the numbers before.
    //If it is valid I'm updating the state of the display, carrying the output with the new 
    //value. for example output: 7+ and the new value: 0 the new state is gonna be 7+0
     if (!isInvalid) {
      this.setState({
        output: `${output}${value}`,
      });
}
```

I was thinking in validate every time I get a number, iterate over the new display value in reverse way until I find a character for example `('+','-','/','*')` in this point I will have a string with the part of the last number in the operation. For example if I have 6+07, after the iteration process I will have 70, the I must to reverse this string and finally cast this getting just the 7.

But I'm thinking that it is not an elegant way to achieve this. Is there a more sophisticated solution?

I followed this tutorial to build the calculator. https://medium.com/@nitinpatel_20236/how-to-build-a-simple-calculator-application-with-react-js-bc10a4568bbd.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply chain `parseInt` (or `parseFloat`) with `toString()`. This will remove leading zeros.

```js
const foo = "07"

const bar = parseInt(foo, 10).toString()

console.log(bar)
```

Comment: Yes, but additionally to this, I have to update all the output display state, I mean currently I have 6+07, my final value is 7, so I have to update the current state to 6+07, in order to display 6+7, I'm struggling with this validation. Thanks!